# I keep getting index out of range error what is wrong with my code?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

My code won't run properly I am trying to get it to find peaks including the end and beginning of the array and then compare all the indexes that aren't the beginning or end to the index before and after them does anyone know why I am getting the out of index range error?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func linearFindPeaks(arg []int) []int {
    peaks := []int{}
    lenArg := len(arg)
    for i := 0; i < lenArg; i++ {
        //if its the first element run this
        //second if statement for the end of array
        // for default statements
        if arg[0] > arg[1] {
            peaks = append(peaks, arg[0])
        } else if arg[lenArg-1] > arg[lenArg-2] {
            peaks = append(peaks, arg[lenArg-1])
        } else if arg[i] > arg[i+1] && arg[i] > arg[i-1] && arg[i] != arg[0] && arg[i] != arg[lenArg-1] {
            peaks = append(peaks, arg[i])
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(peaks)
    return peaks
}

func main() {}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2JRgEyRA50

Comment: I invite you to add a main function to allow a faster debug. 
Anyway, depending on your array `arg[lenArg-1]` and `arg[lenArg-2]` may throw out of range exception.

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities i can see. Firstly, in the first `else if`:

```
}else if arg[lenArg - 1] > arg[lenArg -2] {
```

If `lenArg` is `1` then `lenArg-2`will be `-1`. This means `arg[lenArg-2]` is `arg[-1]` which will give you out of bounds.

Secondly, in the second `else if`:

```
} else if arg[i] > arg[i+1] ... {
```

On the last iteration over the loop, `i` will be `lenArg-1`, if you add `1` to this you'll get `arg[lenArg-1+1]` or `arg[lenArg]` which will out of bounds. (The last available index is at `lenArg-1`)